# PDF does not show complete with datatable button

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to visualize the pdf of almost all the datatable's columns, however, the pdf document does not show the last two columns. Having said that, I have two questions. First how can I make the column "Opciones" not to appear, and the second is, how can I make the pdf to show complete? I would appreciate any help. Thanks

This is my code:

```
function listar() {
    tabla = $('#tbllistado').dataTable({
        "aProcessing": true,//activamos el procedimiento del datatable
        "aServerSide": true,//paginacion y filrado realizados por el server
        dom: 'Bfrtip',//definimos los elementos del control de la tabla
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdf'
        ],
        "ajax":
        {
            url: '../ajax/venta.php?op=listar',
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        },
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 5,//paginacion
        "order": [[0, "desc"]]//ordenar (columna, orden)
    }).DataTable();
}
```

and the images of the results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1tZj.png)

And also this is the pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McwLa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by myself, all I had to do was to add some parameters to the pdf button. Thank you so much

```
buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
                }
            }
        ]
```